# FB native login SessionState CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED

Tags: java, android, facebook

I know there are couple of other questions like this, but nothing worked from there.

The code is from here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook
There are not modifications.

When i am logging FB always returns CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED.

I generated Key Hash with this:

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

and checked it with this:

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.example.facebooktest", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            String s = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.d("KeyHash:", s);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

So the problem is not with the key. I have checked and double checked everything but i still don't know from where is the problem coming.

I tried all the sample apps that come with the SDK and all of them return the same thing. Also i tried it on 3 different devices same problem.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Print out the "exception" parameter in your callback, it should tell you why the login failed.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same type of problem, where the facebook app would never give me an active session. If the app wasn't installed (there by using the WebView for log in to facebook) it did how ever work. I hadn't change any thing, and was signing with out production key (as always, which have never caused any problems).

What i found was that i had to update the hashes in the facebook dashboard (i actually have the production key in there twice now..?), and it immediately started to work.I have no idea why or what it fixed, but somehow it fixed it.

Hope it helps.